# HOW to add increment value to $_POST['variable'] in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, forms, http-post

I am using dynamic form where user add more input text boxes for a certain field he want and the name of each box change with an increment like:

```
<form method="post" action="somescript.php">
<input type="text" name="textbox" />
<input type="text" name="textbox1" />
<input type="text" name="textbox2" />
<input type="text" name="textbox3" />
.... and so on
</form>
```

I want to echo these data following a loop:

```
<?PHP
  $k=$_POST['counter']; //counter value coming as post variable
  for($i=1$i<=$k;$k++){
    echo $_POST['textbox'.$i]; //something like this......?
  }
?>
```

Please reply.

Comment: This seems like something you would want to use _javascript_ for, otherwise every time the user adds a new field, the page will reload and clear all existing data - unless you explicitly preserve it via _GET/POST_ params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array notation instead.

```
<form method="post" action="somescript.php">
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" />
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" />
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" />
<input type="text" name="textbox][" />
.... and so on
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, `$_POST['textbox']` will then be an array, and you can loop over it:

```
foreach ($_POST['textbox'] as $textbox) {
    echo $textbox;
}
```

Comment: This should be considered the correct answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue because I had blocks of data that needed to be created dynamically and

```
echo $_POST["textbox$i"];
```

worked without the concatenation in it. Let me know if this is bad practice, it works in my situation though. The array way didn't work for me. Sorry for posting this on a 3 year old question. I'm not sure if that's bad practice. Thanks.